# Program won't upload to emulator - IOException

Tags: android-emulator

Whenever I try to run a program in the android emulator, I get the following console output:

...
[2010-08-20 12:40:55 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-08-20 12:41:04 - HelloAndroid] Failed to upload HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-08-20 12:41:04 - HelloAndroid] java.io.IOException: Unable to upload file: timeout
[2010-08-20 12:41:04 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!

It ran fine earlier in the day. I have tried restarting eclipse, killing the adb process, restarting my computer, and running eclipse as administrator. Nothing works. I am using windows 7 64-bit with eclipse helios 64 bit. Can someone please tell me what the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating a new [AVD](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html), maybe your previous one got corrupted for some reason.